# Is there a way to improve this LINQ?

Tags: linq, list

Code :

```
IList<Evento> Eventi = new List<Evento>() { };

Eventi = (from Evento ae in new Eventi()
             select ae).ToList();

if (strNome != "")
{
    Eventi = Eventi.Where(e => e.Titolo.ToLower().Contains(strNome.ToLower()) && e.Titolo != "").ToList();
}

if (strComune != "")
{
    Eventi = Eventi.Where(e => e.Comune != null && e.IDComune == strComune).ToList();
}

if (strMesi != "")
{
    Eventi = Eventi.Where(e => MesiSelezionati.Contains(DateTime.Parse(e.DataEvento).Month.ToString())).ToList();
}
```

I know all query are merged, during running time of code, in only 1 LINQ statement. But, as you can see, I convert the List -> ToList() many times. This, I think, here, is the only part when I waste time, right? How can I avoid this and improve performance?

Comment: when you cast the collection to list you basically fetch iqueryable to list. If you do not cast it untill you need the results, you should improove the query

Answer (score 4):

Why so many lists/ToLists?  What's wrong with IEnumerable/IQueryable?

```
var eventi = (from Evento ae in new Eventi() 
             select ae);

if (strNome != "") 
{ 
    eventi = eventi.Where(e => e.Titolo.ToLower().Contains(strNome.ToLower()) && e.Titolo != "");
} 

if (strComune != "") 
{ 
    eventi = eventi.Where(e => e.Comune != null && e.IDComune == strComune);
} 

if (strMesi != "") 
{ 
    eventi = eventi.Where(e => MesiSelezionati.Contains(DateTime.Parse(e.DataEvento).Month.ToString()));
} 

// if you do need a list, then do so right at the end
var results = eventi.ToList();
```

---

EDIT:  To clarify some principles for Caesay

Caesay, thank you for taking the time to test the implementation to confirm the deferred loading works as intended; much kudos!

I wanted to explain why I disagree with your comment about the above approach being *optimized at run-time* whilst yours being *optimized at compile time*.

The above approach is, for lack of a better description, the *intended* approach.  This is because the assignments to *eventi* are correctly appending expressions to the *source* of the IEnumerable/IQueryable.

Your approach is only supported by certain providers, such as Linq to Entities, which expect a [*Func(Of T, TResult)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) to be passed to their [*Select*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx), [*Where*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803), etc Extensions.  Many providers, such as Entity Framework and Linq to Sql provider, provide [*IQueryable*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx), which implements *IEnumerable*.  The difference here, however, is that *IQueryable*'s [*Select*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743.aspx), [*Where*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx), etc, expect you to pass an [*Expression(Of Func(Of T, TResult))*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx).

In those cases, your code will not behaveas expected (or at least as I would expect), because Expression does not support multi-line lambda, where as the compiler will correctly interpret my statements and compile them into Expression>.

As a simple example:

```
public void Test<T1, T2>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T1, T2>> arg)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void Test()
{
    Test((string x) => x.ToLower());
    Test((string x) =>
    {
        return x.ToLower();
    });
}
```

In the above example, the first expression is absolutely fine.  The second, which is based loosely on your example, will fail with the exception:

```
A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree
```

The compiler may recognise your statements as a *Func* which it knows is supported on IEnumerable.  The result would be that the query to the database would not include any of your Where expressions, returning the whole data source.  Once the data source was in-memory, it would then apply your IEnumerable Where clauses.  Personally, I much prefer passing these kind of things to the database so that I'm not wasting bandwidth on returning much more data than I need, and I can utilise my Data Sources ability to filter data which is likely (and vastly in Sql Server's case) better than doing so in-memory.

I hope that makes sense and is of some use to you?

Comment: so here "var", in the first line, is like an IEnumerable. How can I declare an empty ienumerable?

Comment: Because it's in a foreach cycle. `Enumerable.Empty<Evento>();` ?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply @markzzz.  You use _var_ to declare a variable that infer's it's type from the assignment, otherwise called an implicit declaration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: yeah! but if there are no elements into Event(), a foreach will cause a null exception?

Comment: @markzzz I'm not sure what you mean by "Event()"?  "Eventi()" perhaps?  If so, _foreach_, _Select_, _Where_ etc will all work against a collection that contains no Elements.  You are declaring _new Eventi()_ in the above snippet, so I assume it cannot be null?  (Note, a collection that == null is very different to a collection with no elements).  Hope that helps?  If not, add a little example to your question and drop a comment on here to let me know.

Comment: @Smudge202: I really appreciate the time you put into editing your answer to correct my misunderstanding and just want to say thank-you for that. As it was not related to the Op's question at all it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluent syntax to start with (to avoid List).

Alternatively you can combine the condition in one query.

```
Eventi =(new Eventi()).Where(e => e.Titolo.ToLower().Contains(strNome.ToLower()) && e.Titolo != "" && e.Comune != null && e.IDComune == strComune &&MesiSelezionati.Contains(DateTime.Parse(e.DataEvento).Month.ToString())).ToList();
```

I have assumed Eventi implements IEnumerable < Evento > as you have used similarly in query syntax

Comment: I love one-liners, but this approach I find to be very difficult to read.  Perhaps you could maintain the one-liner approach but add in new lines before the _.Where_ and _&&_'s so it's broken down into logical chunks?

Comment: i also love one lines, but when some predicate becomes longer, i prefer either splitting in different lines, or making named method (instead of anonymous one)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you test for strNome not being empty, the second half of your first Where clause will never be called.

So  `e.Titolo.ToLower().Contains(strNome.ToLower()) && e.Titolo != ""`
   can be written `e.Titolo.ToLower().Contains(strNome.ToLower())`

You could also calculate `strNome.ToLower()` outside the lambda to ensure it is calculated just once.

In addition you can streamline the Where clauses and remove the ToList() as others have suggested.

Another alternative you should be aware of is [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) which allows you to combine lambda expressions more easily which although not needed in this case since `Where ... Where` is good enough for an 'And', you might one day need an 'Or' and then you need a different solution.

Or, better yet, use the method explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx) to create your own `And` and `Or` methods that perform Expression 'magic' to give you a single expression that you can hand off to Linq-to-Sql or any other Linq provider.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the whole thing into 1 linq query like this:

```
        var eventi = from Evento e in new Eventi() select e;

        eventi = eventi.Where(e =>
        {
            if (strNome != "")
            {
                if(!(e.Titolo.ToLower().Contains(strNome.ToLower()) && e.Titolo != ""))
                    return false;
            }
            if (strComune != "")
            {
                if(!(e.Comune != null && e.IDComune == strComune))
                    return false;
            }
            if (strMesi != "")
            {
                if(!(MesiSelezionati.Contains(DateTime.Parse(e.DataEvento).Month.ToString())))
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        });

        var results = eventi.ToList();
```

This is logically equivalent to your code, but should be much faster. Although I was not able to test it, because I can't compile it.

Comment: it is not a exlusive if/else. There are only if...if...if... :)

Comment: @markzzz: Incorrect. He does 3 linq queries - I do 1. Which in turn makes mine (approximately) 3 times faster.

Comment: But them are merged into 1 query, at run-time. Not 3 separate query...(for what I know)

Comment: @markzzz Correct, and something for you to note possibly caesay?  _IEnumerable<T>_ and _IQueryable<T>_ are not evaluated until they are enumerated (i.e. by calling _ToList()_).  The code in the OP does do 3 queries, mine does not.

Comment: @Smudge202: I know the concept of delayed execution - but my understanding was as soon as you did anything with the enumerator that it would evaluate the results. And also that by running another query on it, it would force the previous query to evaluate.

Comment: @Smudge202: However I ran my own tests and see that they are optimized at run-time. Thanks for improving my understanding of .Net JIT optimizations, but I would still recommend not relying on them too heavily. I would suggest that while yours is optimized at run-time, mine is optimized at compile time.

Comment: @casesay - I disagree with your point about optimisations - I've added a section to my answer that hopefully clarifies why.